# Server getting error when trying to send PKPush

Tags: ios, swift, push, voip

I am using the following code on the iOS side to get PKPush notifications working correctly. didUpdate is getting called and the server is sending a push to the correct token but the server is getting this error:

> An error response packet was received from the APNS server: APNS: [1] Invalid token.

```
func voipRegistration() {
            let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            voipRegistry.delegate = self
            voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushType.voIP]
        }


        func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didInvalidatePushTokenFor type: PKPushType) {
            //
        }

        func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType) {
            //
        }

        func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
            NSLog("Device token \(deviceTokenString)")
        }


        func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
            //
        }
```

I have the following background modes set:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
    <string>voip</string>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

And I am pointing to my development certificate while the server is pointing to the sandbox. What am I doing wrong?